# Trying to identify this trade paperback containing several Fantastic Four stories

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, fantastic-four

I'm trying to identify a Fantastic Four trade paperback I read approx. 10 years ago but that might have been older (1990s, early 2000s). It contained several distinct stories:

- A story where Reed and the gang are searching for an evil(??) satellite that's crashed on Earth and has the power to absorb technology. Reed finally destroys its remnants using some sort of material that the satellite cannot destroy.
- A story that was "narrated" by Ben (the text boxes were all Ben's monologue). The Fantastic Four notices that there is a large number four on the moon. Reed Richards is uncomfortable with using a rocket to go to the moon, but they do so anyway, and they fight a supervillain who has defaced the moon to fight the Fantastic Four. There's a lot about Ben and Reed's relationship, how Reed regrets the events that gave Ben his new body and is uncomfortable doing things that he's unsure of. I'm fairly sure it was a self-contained story.